# Limit matching results of grep regex multi-line search to one

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, grep, pcre

I've got some text files partly containing XML data. E.g.:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..."><soap:Body><Data><SpecificTag>Some
multiline data
that I need to
extract.
</SpecificTag></Data></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I need to do multi-line search and extract only the data within specific tags. I tried a few solutions found here, and the best result I got using `grep` in perl-regexp mode:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)<SpecificTag>\K.*?(?=</SpecificTag>)' filename
```

But sometimes file may contain two or more identical blocks with matching patterns. How can I change this regular expression to limit the grep output to first occurrence? `-m` argument does not work in case of perl regex mode.

p.s.: Other working solutions are okay, but using XML-specific tools is not an option. Files are actually memory dumps infiltrated with `strings` utility, they contain only fragments of SOAP transactions among other data. I have to use regex in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something for sed:

```
/<SpecificTag>/,/<\/SpecificTag>/ {
  /<SpecificTag>/ {
    s/.*<SpecificTag>//
  }
  /<\/SpecificTag>/ {
    s/<\/SpecificTag>.*//
    p
    q
  }
  p
}
```

Put that in a file, say `foo.sed`, and use `sed -n -f foo.sed filename.xml`.

The way this works is as follows:

```
/<SpecificTag>/,/<\/SpecificTag>/ {
```

means that all this only happens for lines between `<SpecificTag>` and `</SpecificTag>`.

```
  /<SpecificTag>/ {
    s/.*<SpecificTag>//
  }
```

means that within that constraint, the line containing `<SpecificTag>` has it and everything before it removed.

```
  /<\/SpecificTag>/ {
    s/<\/SpecificTag>.*//
    p
    q
  }
```

means that the line containing `</SpecificTag>` has it and everything after it removed, is printed, and then sed quits. This is how only the first match is extracted.

```
  p
}
```

means that all other lines within the first constraint (between the tags) are printed. This includes the rest of the first line after the substitution.

If you prefer to have it in one long command:

```
sed -n -e '/<SpecificTag>/,/<\/SpecificTag>/ { /<SpecificTag>/ { s/.*<SpecificTag>// }; /<\/SpecificTag>/ { s/<\/SpecificTag>.*//; p; q }; p }' filename.xml
```

...but of course that makes it harder to see what is happening, and sed scripts are already notoriously difficult to read.

Addendum: An addition you may want to consider is to make

```
  /<\/SpecificTag>/ {
    s/<\/SpecificTag>.*//
    p
    q
  }
```

into

```
  /<\/SpecificTag>/ {
    s/<\/SpecificTag>.*//
    /^$/ !p
    q
  }
```

or perhaps even with

```
    /^ *$/ !p
```

...in which case the remainder of the line containing `</SpecificTag>` will only be printed if it is not empty (first version) or contains more than spaces (second version). This prevents (possibly) superfluous line breaks at the end of the extracted text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `\A` anchor to match start of the very first line.

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\A.*?<SpecificTag>\K.*?(?=</SpecificTag>)' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..."><soap:Body><Data><SpecificTag>Some
multiline first data
that I need to
extract.
</SpecificTag></Data></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
<SpecificTag>Some
multiline second data
that I need to
extract.
```

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?s)\A.*?<SpecificTag>\K.*?(?=</SpecificTag>)' file
Some
multiline first data
that I need to
extract.
```

OR

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\A.*?<SpecificTag>\K(?:(?!</?SpecificTag>).)*(?=</SpecificTag>)' file
```

Comment: If I close the second `SpecificTag` in your input file, this doesn't limit the output to the data in the first one. I don't think this works.

Comment: Add `</SpecificTag>` to the end of `file` and run the grep command again. You'll get the multiline data twice (once from each tag).

Comment: I'm afraid the new one does the same as the old one for me, whether I feed it valid XML or not. In any case, OP is not parsing valid XML but sanitized memory dumps.

Comment: It's upto the op not me. Both grep and sed are not the right tools for parsing xml files.

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj, but Wintermute is right: duplicated data in my case is fully matching the pattern, it has opening and closing tags in every occurrence. If you add closing tags to the end of your example, the result of both your expressions will still contain two duplicates.